# Jeditable plugin - All columns editable at same time

Tags: jquery

I am working with **[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)** plugin. What I'm trying to do is click a button and all the fields in a certain row become editable and automatically go to their editable state. So in other words, I have a table, I want to click an *"Edit"* button on the side of a row and all the columns in that row become editable. Is this possible?

Comment: I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375705/jeditable-plugin-all-columns-editable-at-same-time/4392708#4392708) with a working jsFiddle-demo.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.
Let's say you use [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) the way that the user has to confirm the modification, the same way as on the demo site; look at the "Character counter" section: [Jeditable Custom Inputs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html).

And than you have to put a button somewhere, which causes the elements to be editable. For example, if the elements have the class "`edit`" (e.g.: `<div class="edit">blah blah</div>`) and in the Jeditable code the `event:'dblclick'` is set (which means you have to double-click to edit the field), the following code does exactly what you want (*tested*, working!):

```
<div>
  <div class="edit charcounter">blah blah</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="edit_all_btns">Click this button and all the fields will become editable!</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".charcounter").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", {
    indicator: "<img src='http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/img/indicator.gif'>",
    type: "charcounter",
    submit: 'OK',
    tooltip: "Click to edit...",
    onblur: "ignore",
    charcounter: {
      characters: 60
    },
    event: 'dblclick'
  });

  $('.edit_all_btns').click(function () {
    $('.edit').dblclick();
  });

});
// -->
</script>
```

## Demo

But here's a more elaborated, working jsFiddle-example with a table, where you can try the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/qjrJX/